# Performance improvement of Ubuntu on soc board

Tags: 12.04, performance

I am trying to set up Ubuntu on soc board (Cubietruck) which has 8Gb flash, 2 Gb Ram, with external SSD - 128 GB.

Currently I have installed the Ubuntu on hard drive. Its performance seems moderate but I believe that moving the some part of OS on flash would make it faster.

Is it possible to run bare essential part of kernel on flash and everything else on SSD.

Can someone please help me understand how to identify the files to be moved to flash ?

Comment: How about installing OS on ssd?

Comment: Which ubuntu flavor are you running?

Comment: Its 'Linaro' linux for arm, currently Cubietruck has support for the same

Answer (score 0):

as @Aditya Patil suggest the best way is to install everything on ssd. 
But if you doesn't want to re-install ubuntu u can move some directory on otherpartition.

To do this I suggest you to start a live cd , then mount two disk in this way:
(I suppose sda are your standard disk and sdb the ssd disk)

`mkdir standard-disk
mount /dev/sda1 standard-disk
mkdir quick-disk
mount /dev/sdb1 quick-disk
cp -vfr standard-disk/usr/* quick-disk/
rm -vfr standard-disk/usr`

Then modify the standard-disk/etc/fstab file adding this line

`/dev/sdb1  /usr ext4 defaults,noatime 0 2`

Obiouvsly you can repeat this action for other partition; for example if your /dev/sda2 is your home dir you can move it to /dev/sdb2, then add a fstab line like above.

Comment: My current installation of OS is on SSD itself, but for some reason it runs slowly. That's the reason I wanted to move core part of kernel on flash which may improve the performance.